# This function or variable may be unsafe

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile a c++ console project. However,  the compiler is giving me the following error.

1>C:\Users\my_pc\Desktop\MyFolder\test1.cpp(105,1): error C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

Here is the part of the code that is preventing the program compile. I appreciate any help to resolve this issue. Thanks.

```
void Coin::flip()
{
   int myFlip;
   // Assign random numbrer to myFlip

   myFlip = rand() % 2 + 1;
   if (myFlip == 1)
   {

      strcpy(coin_side, "heads");
   }
      else
   {

      strcpy(coin_side, "tails");
   }
}
```

Comment: If you use `std::string`, you could do `coin_side = "heads";`.

Comment: The best advice is above, however if you are forced to stick to using c-strings instead of c++ strings you can do what the message tells you. ***To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS***

Comment: Yes that is what I did to suppress the warning. I took a shortcut and added the following at the top of my code:#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif  That did the trick. Thanks.